# How to configure a Google App Engine nodejs8 Standard Environment for React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have developed a simple app using React and Node.js 8 for Google App Engine. It works fine in the Flexible Environment, but if I try to deploy it on the Standard Environment, I am getting "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 errors. I can't find any more information on what is going wrong beyond that.

How can I configure it so that it will work in the standard environment?

app.standard.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs8

handlers:
  - url: /
    script: src/index.js
  - url: /src
    script: index.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "eventpub",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.x.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.11.0",
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-collapsible": "^2.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-json-viewer": "^1.7.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

project folder structure

```
node_modules
public
- public/index.html
- public/manifest.json
src
- src/App.css
- src/App.js
- src/App.test.js
- src/index.css
- src/index.js
- src/registerServiceWorker.js
.gcloudignore
.gitignore
app.flexible.yaml
app.standard.yaml
package.json
package-lock.json
README.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by building the react app first (npm run build), deploying the already built version to google cloud, and adding handlers for the built app in app.yaml.

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: build
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that the issue you are experiencing is due to App Engine Standard for Nodejs still being in beta as mentioned over at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#dependencies